# Allow DNS traffic using Nftables

Tags: networking, dns, nftables

I tried the following commands but it still doesn't allow DNS traffic. What am I doing wrong?

```
nft add table inet tarffic
nft add chain inet traffic INPUT '{ type filter hook input priority 100; policy drop; }'
nft add rule inet traffic INPUT ip protocol icmp accept
nft add rule inet traffic INPUT ct state established,related accept
nft add rule inet traffic INPUT udp dport 53 accept
nft add rule inet traffic INPUT tcp dport 53 accept

nft add chain inet traffic OUTPUT '{ type filter hook output priority 100; policy drop; }'
nft add rule inet traffic OUTPUT ip protocol icmp accept
nft add rule inet traffic OUTPUT ct state established,related accept
nft add rule inet traffic OUTPUT udp dport 53 accept
nft add rule inet traffic OUTPUT tcp dport 53 accept
```

Comment: Assuming you are not running your own internet wide DNS system, then shouldn't the inbound be `sport 53`?

Comment: @Bib `ct state established,related accept` in `INPUT` should complement `udp|tcp dport 53 accept` in `OUTPUT` though. (And the "other pair" should allow the host to work as a DNS server as well, although I haven't really tested.) One case I could think of that isn't covered by the rules here is that the host forwards DNS requests on IP level (IP forwarding + DNAT). On the other hand, perhaps these aren't the only rules / table in nft, or maybe there are rules in the legacy (non-nft) iptables. I'd suggest the OP add `nft list ruleset` and `iptables-save` to the question.

Comment: Were you able to figure out a solution to this?